# glGetUniformLocation call crashes program

Tags: opengl, glsl

The chunk of code below works correctly as-is. But if I uncomment the call to glGetUniformLocation() it crashes at that line:

```
GLint pipeline;
glGenProgramPipelines(1, &pipeline);
glUseProgram(0);
glBindProgramPipeline(pipeline);

GLint vert_pgm = glCreateShaderProgramv(...);
glUseProgramStages(pipeline, GL_VERTEX_SHADER_BIT, vert_pgm);

GLint frag_pgm = glCreateShaderProgramv(...);
glUseProgramStages(pipeline, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER_BIT, frag_pgm);

//  If I uncomment the line below, it crashes:
//
//  GLint myArg_loc = glGetUniformLocation(frag_pgm, "material_id");

glBindBufferBase(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, ubo_index, mp_data->ubo);
glBindVertexArray(vao);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)
...
glEnableVertexAttribArray(10)
glBindVertexBuffer(...);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ...);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, ...);
```

The inputs for the fragment shader are declared as follows:

```
layout( binding = 0, std140, column_major ) 
uniform uniform_data
{
    transform_data transform;
    material_data  material;
    lighting_data  lighting;
    vec4 select;
    vec4 normal;
} 
uniforms;

uniform int material_id;

in attribute_data
{
    smooth vec4 pos;
    smooth vec4  colour;
    smooth float radius; 
    smooth vec3  tangent; 
    smooth vec3  normal;    
    flat int  face_id;
}
inputs;
```

Any ideas why it's crashing?

Is it not legal to use interface blocks and individual uniforms together in the same shader?

Comment: A GL programm should never crash. If it does, it likely is a driver bug. For your weird case, is `glGetUniformLocation` a valid pointer to function?

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: I suggest trying glUseProgram(frag_pgm) before glGetUniformLocation. And though it isn't very elegant, sometimes "don't do that" is the only solution to a driver bug. Move material_id into your uniform_data block :-(

Answer (score 0):

Check for: **NULL pointer** AND **recursion**.

My wrapper function for glGetUniformLocation was calling itself rather
than the function pointer it was supposed to wrap. Ironically the wrapper function is there for my protection. It checks to make sure the function pointer isn't null and throws an error if it is.

```
typedef  
    GLint                                     
    (*PFN_glGetUniformLocation)               
    (                                         
    /**/    GLuint         program 
    ,       const GLchar*     name 
    ); 

PFN_glGetUniformLocation                   
pfn_glGetUniformLocation;                  

GLint                                      
glGetUniformLocation                       
(                                          
/**/    GLuint         program 
,       const GLchar*     name 
){           
    //! My Mistake:                  !//
    //! Exists(glGetUniformLocation);!//
    //! return(glGetUniformLocation( !//       
    //!     program, name            !//
    //! ));;                         !//

        //:My Fix:
        Exists(pfn_glGetUniformLocation);
        return(pfn_glGetUniformLocation(         
            program, name 
        ));;     
}
```

"Exists" throws an error if the function pointer is NULL.

"pfn" is a prefix for "Pointer to a FuNction"